# How to solve multiple inequalities?

Tags: inequality, factorial

$$100!=K(2!)^x(5!)^y(7!)^z$$
Find the maximum value of $x+y+z$.

I tried to open all the brackets and I got $$100!=K(2)^{x+3y+4z}(3)^{y+2z}(5)^{y+z}(7)^{z}$$

By using greatest integer function, I got the following inequalities:
$$x+3y+4z\le97$$ $$y+2z\le48$$ $$y+z\le24$$ $$z\le16$$
By adding the last two, I got $$y+2z\le40$$
Now I can't figure out how to proceed from here.

Edit: $x, y$ and $z$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: Have you come across the idea of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ nonnegative integers?

Comment: No, @sudeep5221 , what are Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @Righter The technique of Lagrange multipliers is quite common for optimizing functions with constraints. There are a large number of resources on the internet that can help you understand the idea quite easily. The Wikipedia article about it would be a good point to start. However, this technique works only for the case of continuous variables, so I am guessing it would not be so useful for this problem since the variables are integers. (Sorry I didn't realise this earlier). In any case, it is an interesting and a useful concept to know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x,y,z$ are nonnegative integers, as I suppose, then the answer is $97$, achieved when $x=97, y=z=0$.

Just look at the first inequality.  If we decrease $z$ by $1$, we can increase $x$ by $4$, giving a net increase of $3$ to $x+y+z$.  Similarly, if we decrease $y$ by $1$, we can increase $x+y+z$ by $2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @saulspatz but is there a formal method of doing this (one that could be written down as a descriptive answer)?

Comment: Google "integer linear programming."

Comment: @Righter That logic can be formalised easily - there are only finite choices, so there is a maximum.  If $y, z>1$ the procedure above allows to create a larger sum.  +1

Comment: Just $x+y+z\le x+3y+4z\le 97$

Comment: Thanks @NeatMath, that was very helpful